# subtract one from all rows every minute - sql php

Tags: php, sql, mysql, cron, mariadb

I have a database of a number of purchased plans with a value of minutes_left from which I want to subtract 1 number every minute.

Now I am using this **code** using cron job:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pls";
$stmt = $pdo->query($sql);

while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$theM = $row['minutes_left'];
$realM = intval($theM) - 1;
$sqlE = "UPDATE pls SET minutes_left=?";
$stmtE = $pdo->prepare($sqlE);
$stmtE->execute([strval($realM)]);
```

}

But for example, if there are 27 minutes from one, and 12 minutes from another, and 15 minutes from another, all of them will change to 26, 25, etc., and each of them will not reduce theirs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to query them first and then update. You can do the update in a single step.

```
UPDATE pls SET minutes_left = minutes_left - 1
```

If you don't want to go below 0 you can use a max function called [GREATEST()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html).

```
UPDATE pls SET minutes_left = GREATEST(minutes_left - 1, 0)
```

or suggested by [@topsail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1467914/topsail) to decrease only those which are greater than 0.

```
UPDATE pls SET minutes_left = minutes_left - 1 WHERE minutes_left > 0
```

Comment: Perhaps even better: `UPDATE pls SET minutes_left = minutes_left - 1 where minutes_left > 0;`

Answer (score 1):

`UPDATE pls SET minutes_left=?` should be something like `UPDATE pls SET minutes_left=minutes_left-?` or even `UPDATE pls SET minutes_left=minutes_left-1 where minutes_left > 0` Meaning, you don't want update `minutes left` to a literal value, but instead you want to update `minutes_left` to subtract the next minute from it - a calculated value.

But consider setting something like a start time and minutes or an expiration time and then you could just check if expiration time is exceeded without constant updates (this is the same concept as birthdays - do you save Age in your database, or do you save BirthDate in your database. Age is always changing, but BirthDate is a constant you can use to calculate Age.

Comment: It may not be that they have so many minutes from a specific time, it may be (like a phone contract) where you have a certain number of minutes in a month.

Comment: Well you may be right. But if minutes decay every minute ("subtract one every minute") then it sounds time-based, and there would have to be a starting time when the minutes begin to decay - I'll leave my suggestion in my answer in case it's relevant... you have a good point though and I really don't know enough about when or how these minutes are really meant to be subtracted.